# C# Dynamic list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a small entity "Category"

```
Id
Name 
Parent_id
```

I want to override the ToString() with a string of all parents of the item and i dont know how many parents the item have.

```
Example: (pseudo code)
Item1 =>  Id = 1, Name = Computers, Parent_id = null 
Item2 =>  Id = 2, Name = Laptops  , Parent_id = 1
Item3 =>  Id = 3, Name = Acer     , Parent_id = 2
```

On the output from Item3.ToString() i want the result to be `"Computers > Laptops > Acer"`.
And i need it to be dynamic so i dont know how many steps it should take... 
Any fresh idéas?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Just use a `while` a few `if`'s and you should be done no?

Comment: Is this c# or SQL? Because you are aiming for a SQL solution in an OO world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to add the parent item itself (not just the ID) to every item, then it should be easy enough with simple loop:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    List<string> names = new List<string>();
    names.Add(this.Name);
    Category parent = this.Parent;
    while (parent != null)
    {
        names.Add(parent.Name);
        parent = parent.Parent;
    }
    names.Reverse();
    return string.Join(" > ", names);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this recursively:

```
public overrides string ToString()
{
    string build = parent.ToString();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(build)) build += " > ";
    build += Name;
    return build
}
```

Something along the lines of the above should do it - each Entity will call ToString on its parent so you get the list of all entities in the hierarchy. This will work however deep the hierarchy gets (within reason).

Note: you'll need a reference to the parent to do this, either you can use a property, or you can look the entity up using the parentid property you've already got.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category Parent { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Parent == null 
            ? Name
            : string.Format("{0} > {1}", Parent, Name);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
item1 = new Category{Id = 1, Name = "Computers"};
item2 = new Category{Id = 2, Name = "Laptops", Parent = item1};
item3 = new Category{Id = 3, Name = "Acer", Parent = item2};

Debug.Print(item3.ToString());
Debug.Print(item2.ToString());
Debug.Print(item1.ToString());
```

Result:

```
Computers > Laptops > Acer
Computers > Laptops
Computers
```